# Querying Snowflake via ODBC (using PDO) in PHP returns incorrect data

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake via their ODBC driver in PHP (CentOS 6 and 7) and utilize PDO for easier access.

ODBC driver seems to be installed and working properly, as the native ODBC functions in PHP work pretty well:

```
$dsn = "Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;Server=" . SNOWFLAKE_HOST;
$dsn .= ";Account=" . SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT;
$dsn .= ";Port=" . SNOWFLAKE_PORT;
$dsn .= ";Schema=" . SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA;
$dsn .= ";Warehouse=" . SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE;
$dsn .= ";Database=" . SNOWFLAKE_DATABASAE;

$conn_id = odbc_connect($dsn, SNOWFLAKE_USER, SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD);
odbc_exec($conn_id, "USE WAREHOUSE " . SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE);

$res = odbc_exec($conn_id, 'SHOW TABLES IN SCHEMA ' . SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA . ';');
if ($res) {
    print "Tables in schema\n";
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}

$res = odbc_exec($conn_id, 'SELECT * FROM TEST;');
if ($res) {
    print "Test table content\n";
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

returns

```
Tables in schema
Array
(
    [created_on] => 2015-09-09 17:34:43.517000
    [name] => TEST
    [database_name] => TESTSUITE
    [schema_name] => TESTSUITE
    [kind] => TRANSIENT
    [comment] =>
    [cluster_by] =>
    [rows] => 3
    [bytes] => 8192
    [owner] => TESTSUITE
    [account_name] => ****
    [retention_time] => 1
)
Test table content
Array
(
    [C1] => c
    [C2] =>
)
Array
(
    [C1] => a
    [C2] =>
)
Array
(
    [C1] => a
    [C2] =>
)
```

and that is exactly what I get when I query the DB directly.

But when I want to use PDO, the results are getting weird.

```
$dsn = "Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;Server=" . SNOWFLAKE_HOST;
$dsn .= ";Account=" . SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT;
$dsn .= ";Port=" . SNOWFLAKE_PORT;
$dsn .= ";Schema=" . SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA;
$dsn .= ";Database=" . SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE;
$dsn .= ";Warehouse=" . SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE;

$pdo = new PDO("odbc:" . $dsn, SNOWFLAKE_USER, SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$pdo->exec("USE WAREHOUSE " . SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE);

$query = 'SHOW TABLES IN SCHEMA ' . SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA . ';';
$statement = $pdo->query($query);
print "Tables in schema\n";
print "Rows: " . $statement->rowCount() . "\n";
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    print_r($row);
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM TEST;';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
print "Test table content\n";
print "Rows: " . $statement->rowCount() . "\n";
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

returns

```
Tables in schema
Rows: 1
Array
(
    [created_on] => 2015-09-09 17:34:43.517000
    [name] =>
    [database_name] =>
    [schema_name] =>
    [kind] =>
    [comment] =>
    [cluster_by] =>
    [rows] =>
    [bytes] =>
    [owner] =>
    [account_name] =>
    [retention_time] =>
)
Test table content
Rows: 3
```

Note: there is not further output after `Rows: 3`.

So PDOStatement knows the correct number of rows, but the content of `SHOW TABLES` is incomplete and `SELECT * FROM TEST` is somehow missing completely (`$statement->fetch()` returns `false` immediately).

Any idea if any PDO options would help here?

I have also noticed, that native ODBC functions consume ~200MB of memory in this case, which seems a lot.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @DipuR unfortunately, we're still using ODBC.

Comment: Same thing here. @OndřejHlaváček any updates on this? Did you manage to make it work with PDO?

Comment: @DuruCanCelasun no, I gave up and ended up using ODBC

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem, where CAST did not work correctly through PDO with Snowflake.

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[SL009]: <>: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]No columns were bound prior to
>   calling SQLFetch or SQLFetchScroll

Long story short, after exchanging a couple of e-mails with Snowflake support, we found out the PDO is not supported by Snowflake.

> At this time, we do not support PHP PDO resulting from some issues
>   found due to the binding of STRING/VARCHAR type and columns size being
>   16M bytes. It was a decision to not move forward with supportability.
>   You can continue to use PHP with ODBC, however, we may not be able to
>   address issues/bugs as they arise.

So your best bet is to use native `odbc_*` family of functions from PHP (this is what we're doing).