# Cannot connect to Snowflake Database [PHP]

Tags: php, database, pdo, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The structure of the table I'm trying to reach is as such:

- Database: INTERNAL_STUFF
- Schema: INTERNAL_TEST
- Table: TEST_TABLE_SIMPLE

I create a PDO as such:

```
    $dbh = new PDO("snowflake:account=$this->account", $this->user, $this->password);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

If I use this query:

```
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM INTERNAL_STUFF.INTERNAL_TEST.TEST_TABLE_SIMPLE");
```

I end up getting this response - 'Schema 'INTERNAL_STUFF.INTERNAL_TEST' does not exist or not authorized.'. So it appears to be treating the database and the schema as just the schema.

If I use the same query but drop the database from the front:

```
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM INTERNAL_TEST.TEST_TABLE_SIMPLE");
```

I end up getting this response - 'SQLSTATE[22000]: Data exception: 90105 Cannot perform SELECT. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.'

What am I doing wrong here? My user has access to the correct role to view the table, and that exact query (the longer of the two) works just fine in a Snowflake Worksheet.

Comment: You can specify the schema when you do `new PDO` in a parameter. You may refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495330/querying-snowflake-via-odbc-using-pdo-in-php-returns-incorrect-data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying Snowflake via ODBC (using PDO) in PHP returns incorrect data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495330/querying-snowflake-via-odbc-using-pdo-in-php-returns-incorrect-data)

Comment: That would work! The core of the issue was that the table I was trying to access required permission A. My user had permission A, but they were defaulted to permission B. I was able to resolve using a snowflake worksheet and querying: 'ALTER USER username SET DEFAULT_ROLE roleB'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also set the default namespace(database & Schema) for your user using Alter User statement.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#usage-notes

Comment: This works! However I found my core problem - The table I was trying to access required permission A. My user had permission A, but they were defaulted to permission B. I was able to resolve using a snowflake worksheet and querying: 'ALTER USER username SET DEFAULT_ROLE roleB'

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute query  USE DATABASE INTERNAL_STUFF and next query USE SCHEMA INTERNAL_TEST before you execute your main Sql query.

Comment: I could, but down the line I'll need to access other databases and schemas. This does work though, but I found a better solution! Thank you!